# How to apply condition to Laravel eloquent relation

Tags: database, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.4

I have a ProcessHistory and Person model I need a eloquent code for relation with multiple condition. 
Conditions:
    1. oindex = oindex
    2. pat_id = pat_id

I want a eloquent code to get result of the following sql code

```
select * from tbl_process_history as s join tbl_persons as p on (s.oindex = p.oindex and s.pat_id = p.pat_id)
```

I need to get all the persons having same oindex and pat_id. I have tried with below eloquent code where I can apply condition inside of relation 'own'. Here I can apply only for as static value.

```
ProcessHistory::with(['own'=>function($query){
                return $query->where('pat_id','');
            }])->get();
```

I need a condition inside of relation where I can match pat_id of process history model with persons model.

Comment: Have you tried to use: the relationship for the foreign keys, and a where clause for the other parts?

Answer (score 1):

I just found that I was actually searching for relationship with composite key but this feature is not provided in laravel. It can be solved by using https://github.com/topclaudy/compoships package.

Answer (score 0):

> ProcessHistory::with(['own'=>function($query) use ($param){
>                   return $query->where('pat_id',$param);
>               }])->get();

Comment: $param is dynamic variable in your case it should be person_id